# Is derivative of max(0, x) a diagonal matrix or a vector?

Tags: matrix-calculus

I am reading this amazing [tutorial](https://explained.ai/matrix-calculus/index.html#sec5) and so far everything was clear and good. Unfortunately, there is this section which doesn't make sense to me:
[image]
Why is the derivative not a diagonal matrix but a vector?
According to [this page](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/) tanh's derivative is a diagonal matrix. Tanh and max looks really similar to me. The tutorial also makes it clear that elementwise binary operators have diagonal Jacobians.

And it makes sense: when I differentiate $max(0, x_i)$ w.r.t $x_j$ it should be $0$, right?

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like that are doing a component-wise derivative. I.e. the partial of this vector is defined as the vector of partials if that makes sense. This is what they mean by broadcasting across the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing *anything*, you're just noticing how sloppy the math is in your current field of study.

When operating on a vector argument, functions are applied element-wise. The differential of such a function is given by
$$f = f(x) \quad\implies\quad df = f'(x)\odot dx$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product and $f'(x)$ is the ordinary scalar derivative, which is also applied element-wise.

The Hadamard product between two vectors can always be eliminated by converting one of the vectors into a diagonal matrix, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
a\odot b = Ab \quad\Longleftarrow\quad A = {\rm Diag}(a)
}$$
Eliminating the Hadamard product from the differential yields the gradient as
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= F' = {\rm Diag}\big(f'(x)\big) \\
}$$
These ideas apply not just to $\,\tanh(x)\,$ but to *any* function including
$\,\max(0,x)\;-$ also known as $\,\operatorname{ReLu}(x).$

---

I notice that some of the comments mention *broadcasting* to explain/excuse the sloppy mathematics that afflicts the field of neural nets/machine learning. But broadcasting is something different.

Broadcasting simply pads the dimensions of a
scalar/vector/matrix/tensor via repeated dyadic multiplication with all-ones vectors. For example
$$\eqalign{
&A\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n} \qquad
&v\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times 1} \qquad
{\tt1}\in {\mathbb R}^{n\times 1} \\
&A\odot v
 \qquad&\big({\rm incompatible}\big) \\
&A \odot (v{\tt1}^T)
 \qquad&\big({\rm compatible\,via\,broadcast}\big) \\
}$$
Broadcasting works for simple multiplication and division, but is worthless (and confusing) when calculating gradients and Jacobians.

Answer (score 0):

@KyleC [has the right idea](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) here. Given the functions you're looking at, I suspect you're studying neural nets. These are often implemented with libraries such as numpy to facilitate a [multidimensional generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) of [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422149/what-is-vectorization)). From that perspective, a matrix is a vector of vectors (typically a column vector of row vectors in my experience, but [that's not the only option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))).

Comment: Thanks for the answer both of you. You very well might be right, the only reason I am struggling with this is that nowhere else in the paper they did that. Whenever they talked about derivative it was never the component wise one...
Also, how am I meant to find out which one is it? They seem to have the exact same notation...

Comment: @Kristof Even if you don't pick up on them giving it away with the term *broadcasting* (which I hope they defined for you somewhere), you already know the reason why it's a matrix. When a scalar-to-scalar function $f$ is vectorized viz. $f(x)_i=f(x_i)$, $\partial_if_j=\partial_if(x_j)=f^\prime(x_j)\delta_{ij}$ is not only a matrix, but a diagonal one (which, admittedly, might be identified at times with its leading diagonal, construed as a vector). As you noted, it doesn't matter whether $f(x)=\tanh x$ or $f(x)=\max(0,\,x)$.